# How many extraplanetary celestial bodies has Ender lived on?

Tags: enders-game

Through the main Ender storyline (the books primarily about Ender) how many planets, astroids, and space stations has Ender lived on?

Comment: Two? Did he live anywhere but the main/cadet school and officer/asteroid one?

Comment: @Kevin sorry, my question was meant to include all Ender books where Ender is a primary character. I've editted for clarity.

Comment: Ah. Haven't read the rest.

Comment: Does your question include all of the planets where Ender had served as Speaker?

Comment: What does "extraplanetary" mean? I would've have guessed "other than planets" but you explicitly listited "planets" along with "astroids" etc. And by "lived on" you mean "not merely visited but remained long enough to establish residency" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

I'll go book by book chronologically, adding in spurts.

If someone has more complete answer, please add separately, don't be shy :)

**Current tally (through "Xenocide", but excluding "Children of the Mind") - 27 (Earth, Battle School, Eros, and 24 of Hundred worlds)**

---

**Ender's Game**

- Earth
- Battle School
- Eros
- Shakespeare colony

---

**Ender in Exile**

- Shakespeare colony
- Ganges Colony

---

**First Meetings - Investment Counselor**

- Sorelledolce (where he first meets Jane)

---

**Renegat**

- Catalunya

---

**"The Authorized Ender Companion"** *by Orson Scott Card, Jake Black*

Has the following entry (p 139) slightly expanding on times BETWEEN Ganges and Sorelledolce and Trondheim:

> (4) Various planets, including Helfetica and others not yet identified, where Ender was not a Speaker for the Dead but a research assistant for Valentine...
>
> (6) Rov planet... (This is where people first see Ender with Jane's jewel in his ear, and where he first officially lists "Speaker for the Dead" as occupation.
>
> (7) Various planets, including Moctezuma and others not yet identified, where Ender was a full-time speaker for the Dead

---

**Speaker for the Dead**

- At least 20 planets during his Speaker career

  - Ender was 16 when he left Sheaskpeare

    > "You may have been born fifty-four years ago," said Valentine, "but you're only sixteen, and no matter how old you are, I'm two years older." (*Ender in Exile*)
  - Ender was ~35 on Trondheim, and spent no more than 1/2 year on planets since 25

    > ... since he was twenty-five he had, until Trondheim, never stayed more than six months on any planet. Lightspeed travel between worlds had let him skip like a stone over the surface of time. His students had no idea that their Speaker for the Dead, who was surely no older than thirty-five, ... (*Speaker for the Dead*)
  - It is stated that he never stayed on any world longer than 6 months.
- **The above estimate is later confirmed by Jane, as 24 (including, presumably, Trondheim)**

  > It'll never work, Ender. You see that now, don't you? You've lived on twenty-four of the Hundred Worlds, and there's not a one where even a corner of the world is safe for the buggers to be reborn.
- Trondheim (city of Reykjavik)
- Lusitania

---

**Xenocide**

- Lusitania

---

**Children of the Mind**

- I don't think anything except Lusitania

Comment: The only addition I might make is that he lived on that Starship for 2 years traveling to Shakespeare Colony (originally called something else).

Comment: @Jack - right, though this seems to fall outside of the question ("extraplanetary celestial bodies") - I am not certain but IIRC starships aren't calssified as celestial. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Lets throw a wrench into it and say... shouldn't Young Val and Young Peter be listed since they are "technically" Andrew?

Comment: In the short story *Renegat*, Ender visits the planet Catalunya to speak for a death. (It would be somewhere between Rov and Trondheim.)

Comment: @ibid - is that a new one?

Comment: @DVK - Yes. It's currently only available though Uncle Orson on the Fly.